# db browser sqlite on 16.04

Tags: sqlite

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.
And found db browser for sqlite to be version 3.7.0 
While it was 3.9.99 with 14.04

(and current version is 3.10.1)

Any reason it was switched back to such an earlier version ?

Thanks !
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "db browser for sqlite", you mean "sqlitebrowser"

From [https://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=sqlitebrowser&searchon=names)

```
Package sqlitebrowser

  » trusty (14.04LTS) (devel): GUI editor for SQLite databases [universe]
    2.0.0~beta1+ds.1-3: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
  » xenial (16.04LTS) (devel): GUI editor for SQLite databases [universe]
    3.7.0-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
  » artful (17.10) (devel): GUI editor for SQLite databases [universe]
    3.9.1-2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
  » bionic (18.04LTS) (devel): GUI editor for SQLite databases [universe]
    3.10.1-1.1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
  » cosmic (devel): GUI editor for SQLite databases [universe]
    3.10.1-2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
```

You can see the versions available for each release.

I'm guessing that you may have used a ppa, such as [this one](https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser) or some other source if you had versions as you mention in

> And found db browser for sqlite to be version 3.7.0 While it was 3.9.99 with 14.04